# How can I find the radius and interval of convergece of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty {(x+5)^n} $, and for what value of x does the series converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {(x+5)^n} $$

We talked about this briefly but I'm still pretty confused about how to start this problem.

Comment: Geometric series.

Comment: also: root test

Comment: So should I get it into the form ar^(n-1)?

Comment: Ratio test also works.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** $\sum_n ({\rm stuff})^n$ converges if and only if $|{\rm stuff}| < 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Make a change of variable: set $u=x+5$. The series becommes the geometric series $\,\sum\limits_0^\infty u^n$, which converges to $\dfrac1{1-u}$ iff $\lvert u\rvert<1$. Hence the series converges to  $-\dfrac1{4+x}$ if and only if $-6<x<-4$.